# how do do comparison 2 columns and then calculate in excel?

Tags: excel, list, compare

I have an excel file with following data :

tab AA :
[image]

tab BB :
[image]

this is just a small example, I have more than 300 names and thousands rows in my excel , and the clock under each name does not always match .
I need to substract delay value  from tab BB to tab AA, but only if they have same Name and clock , can I do it in excel ?

if I unmerge name column, then only first row has name , I can still not compare the two list .

Comment: Do you have Microsoft 365? What is the expected result if you e.g. remove `third` from `bbb` in tab `BB` and where?

Comment: if you manually  remove , it is easy , but there are hundreds  of  different lines , so I am seeking a more efficient way to do this

Comment: Is my answer solving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a formula like that:

`=C2-SUMPRODUCT((BB!A$2:A$7=A2)*(BB!B$2:B$7=B2)*(BB!C$2:C$7))`

Assuming you copy this formula on AA sheet cell D2.
After that copy slide down.
You also need to have the 'aaa' or 'bbb' present on each line, no merge allowed.

---

## Addendum

**BB sheet:**
[image]

**AA sheet with numerical results added in column D:**
[image]

**AA sheet with the used formulas:**
[image]